# stripAccents on Thai language

Tags: java, string, scala, diacritics

I am trying to strip accents from Thai language word using the `stripAccent` function in scala language, seems like it's not able to strip the accent.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.stripAccents
println("stripped string " + stripAccents("CLEกอ่ตัRงขึนในปีR"))

stripped string CLEกอ่ตัRงขึนในปีR
```

I am running in Intellij windows environment. It's stripping many other languages like German, Dutch etc.
Has anyone faced similar issue, how did you resolve?

Answer (score 1):

You can use java `Normalizer` :

```
import java.text.Normalizer

val thaiString = "CLEกอ่ตัRงขึนในปีR"

val strippedString = Normalizer.normalize(thaiString, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                    .replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsM}]+", "")

println(strippedString)
//CLEกอตRงขนในปR
```